# handling SEH exception of specific type (access violation only)

Tags: c++, windows, exception, seh

In order to handle access violation exception, project should be configured with SEH Exceptions (/EHa).

I'm looking for handling access violation exceptions only. According to this Microsoft publication [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/eh-exception-handling-model?view=vs-2017), in order to catch this SEH exceptions, one must use the general catch `catch(...)` that will catch all exception.

The question is whether there's an option to handle this exception in specific and leave other SEH unhandled, not necessarily by using the try/catch pattern.

UPDATE: thanks to the link in a comment below, I've found out about the `__try/__except` structure to handle SEH exceptions with many intrinsic functions that may put some more details about the exception nature.

In may case, i only care about AV exception, and i wish to avoid it. However, I'm using C++ and prefer using the standard `try/catch` structure (while configuring The /EHa compiler option).

Is there an option to use those intrinsic function in order to check the exception type in my case ?

Comment: Use an [exception filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/try-except-statement?view=vs-2017)

Comment: Although you cannot actually 'handle' AccessViolations. Once an AV has happenned all bets are realistically off with respoect to the state of your program. Remeber an AV isn't _guaranteed_ on bad access as far as c++ is concerned.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help, i've found out that there are many intrinsic function that may put some more details about the exception nature. In may case, i only care about AV exception, and i wish to avoid it. However, I'm using C++ and prefer using the standard try-catch structure (while configuring The /EHa compiler option. is there an option to use those intrinsic function in order to check the exception type in my case ? thanks !

Answer (score 0):

using `_set_se_translator` I can define the required behavior in SEH exception only, leaving all non-seh exception to the `catch` statement.

I defined the following handling (should be set per thread) :

```
void mySEHtranslator(unsigned int exceptionCode, PEXCEPTION_POINTERS exceptionRecord)
{
    if (exceptionRecord->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode == EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)
    {
        puts("access violation not count");
    }
    else
    {
        throw "1"; // does not suppose to be caught. 
    }
}
```

and in the relevant code section where i want to imply the translator that ignore access violation :

```
void mycode()
{
    _set_seh_translator(mySEHtranslator);

    try {
        .... my code ...
    } 
    catch (...) // does not suppose to catch the "1" 
    {

    }
}
```

additional reference can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/set-se-translator?view=vs-2017)